# How to transpose columns to rows and get the max and min value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

**Input**

| Student_Name | Maths | Science | Social |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 30 | 10 |
| B | 10 | 20 | 30 |

**Output**

| Student_Name | max_sub | min_sub |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Science | Social |
| B | Social | 20Maths |

I tried

```
select student_name,max(marks) m1, min(marks) m2
from
(
select student_name, engg, fre, sp from student)
unpivot (marks for subject in(engg, fre, sp)

) 
group by student_name;
```

but no luck

Comment: Your attempted query shows different "subjects" than you show in your sample data - they are ENGG, FRE, SP rather than MATHS, SCIENCE, SOCIAL. That doesn't look good; if your actual table has ENGG, FRE, SP, then why not show exactly that in your sample, too?

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot, then re-pivot (or, simpler, just aggregate explicitly, as I show below):

```
with
  student(student_name, math, science, social) as (
    select 'A', 20, 30, 10 from dual union all
    select 'B', 10, 20, 30 from dual
  )
select  student_name,
        max(sub) keep (dense_rank last  order by mark nulls first) as max_sub,
        min(sub) keep (dense_rank first order by mark nulls last ) as min_sub
from    student
unpivot (mark for sub in (math as 'Math', science as 'Science',
                          social as 'Social'))
group   by student_name
;

STUDENT_NAME MAX_SUB MIN_SUB
------------ ------- -------
A            Science Social 
B            Social  Math
```

A few things are missing or plain wrong in your problem specification. First and most important, I do hope that in real life you have a student id column - different students may have the same name. (One can work around that for this specific problem, but not in general.)

Then - you need to specify how `null` grades should be treated (what if a student simply doesn't have a grade in Math, for example), and what to show in the case of ties (a student has the same, highest grade in two different subjects). I made one particular set of choices above - they may or may not be right for your use case. Any other choices can be accommodated easily, as soon as you say what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT`. You can use a `CASE` statement and compare the columns values using `GREATEST`, for the maximum, and `LEAST`, for the minimum:

```sql
SELECT student_name,
       CASE
       WHEN maths   = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Maths'
       WHEN science = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Science'
       WHEN social  = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Social'
       END AS minimum,
       CASE
       WHEN maths   = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Maths'
       WHEN science = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Science'
       WHEN social  = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Social'
       END AS maximum
FROM   student;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (Student_Name, Maths, Science, Social) AS
SELECT 'A', 20, 30, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 10, 20, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 10, 10, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | STUDENT_NAME | MINIMUM | MAXIMUM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | Social | Science |
> | B | Maths | Social |
> | C | Maths | Maths |

If you want to show all the subjects in the case of a tie for minimum or maximum then you can use:

```sql
SELECT student_name,
       LTRIM(
            CASE WHEN maths   = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Maths' END
         || CASE WHEN science = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN ', Science' END
         || CASE WHEN social  = LEAST(maths, science, social) THEN ', Social' END,
         ', '
       ) AS minimum,
       LTRIM(
            CASE WHEN maths   = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN 'Maths' END
         || CASE WHEN science = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN ', Science' END
         || CASE WHEN social  = GREATEST(maths, science, social) THEN ', Social' END,
         ', '
       ) AS maximum
FROM   student;
```

Which outputs:

> | STUDENT_NAME | MINIMUM | MAXIMUM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | Social | Science |
> | B | Maths | Social |
> | C | Maths, Science, Social | Maths, Science, Social |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8bc55846baa71f94b5b5e7ffd252f2e5)*